# C++ SunOS ofstream error

Tags: c++, sunos

Folks,
we collect large amounts of data and create error, status, info log files to let us know what's
going on.  We use ofstreams to write to these files.  After some period of time (days), we get a
file error (indicated by .good() call) on one of the ofstreams.  In the affected log file, it
appears that the write of a single line begins but is interrupted by a write of the exact same
line. For example,

```
### Random Line of Text 1 ###
### Random Line of Text 2 ###
### Random Line of Text 3### Random Line of Text 3 ###
```

Each file/ofstream has a single thread that does the actual writing.  We don't flush for performance
reasons and shouldn't have to.
Its always the same type of error.
It does only happen on one of three machines running the same code but we don't see any I/O errors
but maybe not looking in the right place.

Thanks for you time.

Comment: Do you hit 2GB file size?

Comment: Or is the disk you are writing to full?

Comment: Run a memory test. Weirder things have happened due to faulty memory. Also run fsck if you can, and look at kernel messsges.

Comment: this almost sounds like a race-condition. I'm sure everything is not processed in-serial. Can you post a code-snippit?